# NULL implementation in derived function

Tags: c++

In my design I have three classes derived (`Der1`,`Der2`,`Der3`)from a common class (`Base1`)
in 2/3 of these classes have same implementation for virtual function `f1()`.
i.e `f1()` shares same implementation for `Der1` and `Der2` and there is no implementation for `Der3`.

So I kept `f1()` implementation in `Base1` and in `Der3` I override this implementation with a null implementation ( `{}` )

Is this OK?

Comment: If `Der3` doesn't share semantics with `Der1` and `Der2` why does it inherit from the same abstract base class?

Comment: @jaggedSpire  Thanks for the reply. I am implementing a state machine . So its like an event received on derived classes , and all the class must take some action except Der3. So is this question

Comment: I would not do it - you may provide a protected default_f1 in the base class, which can be called from the derived classes.

Comment: It will work yes, but whether it is good design or not we cannot say without further information.

Comment: @DieterLücking , thanks for the reply. however the basic idea of the BASE class is to find the commonality . Now Der1, and Der2 share same function implementation for f1. So Cant I keep them in base class , and Der3 which doesnt have a implementation will override with null implementation . If im keeping default_f1 its altogether a different function

Comment: In addition: You may replace default_f1 by an abstract function f1() = 0 with implementation that can be called from derived classes.

Comment: I would provide what is conceptually *default* behavior for a state as the base class's virtual function implementation, then override with deviations from that. If there *is* no default behavior, I would use a pure virtual function to indicate that. I would think about the decision like this: is it natural that `Der3` has an action, but it happens to do nothing for that action, or does it not make sense for `Der3` to have an action?

Comment: @NeilKirk  Thanks. Basically im trying to implement a hirearchial state machine. I need to take SAME actions for an event in two of the classes, Der1,Der2. But for Der3 for the same event , I do not have any action . Each Der1,Der2,Der3 represent a state here , and F1 represent an action on an event

Comment: @jaggedSpire  Rather than the default behavior , i counted what is the most common behavior across the classes. and most common one i put it in base class, hence an implementation is present in base class. but one particular class does not need any implementation , hence I overrided it with a NULL function . I somehow feel some problem with this design , however I am not able to think any alternative ways

Comment: Can you split the functionality into smaller classes, and then compose your final object from these classes? Inheritance is not directly intended for simple code reuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Der3` naturally has no `f1()` then it fails to be the same sort of thing as `Der1` and `Der2`. You'd be better to have `Base1` which has no `f1()` and derive `Der3` directly from that, then have a `Base2` which implements `f1()` derived from `Base1` and derive `Der1` and `Der2` from that. Thus:

```
class Base1
{
};


class Der3 : public Base1
{
};


class Base2 : public Base1
{
    public:
    f1();
};


class Der1 : Base2
{
};

class Der2 : Base2
{
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your function to do nothing, and if it makes semantic sense that `Der3` overrides the common implementation that instead does nothing, yes, you can make your function do nothing.

This is fine.